# mock a util class to return a mocked object?

Tags: android, mockito, robolectric, android-testing

I've recently started testing on Android and have been playing with Robolectric and Mockito.  I'm able to use Robolectric to simulate the lifecycle of an activity.

However, my code relies on static util funcs to retrieve an object that was previously created during startup.

Is there a way to mock a util class to return a mocked object (preferably of the same type as the real object)?  All the while using Robolectric to control the activity lifecycle.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity
{
  @Override
  public void onCreate( Bundle b )
  {
     super.onCreate(b);
     Something thing = SomeUtil.getSomething();  //I want to put my mocked obj in 'thing'
  }
}
class SomeUtil 
{
  Something something;
  // I want to mock what this func returns by returning my own mock obj
  public static Something getSomething()
  {
     return something; 
  }
}
```

I'm not limited to using Robolectric nor Mockito.

Comment: Here is a handy [matrix](https://code.google.com/p/jmockit/wiki/MockingToolkitComparisonMatrix) that lists popular mocking frameworks and features they support.

Comment: Statics should be avoided. They are a huge pain to test in Java because they **do not get cleared after each test** and thus cause **test pollution** making your tests **fragile and unrepeatable**. I would suggest using dependency injection and consider the singleton pattern instead. This will allow you to easily substitute a mock object.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally used it, but I've heard that [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) allows you to mock static methods.

In my experience though, I've found it nice to just avoid static methods altogether whenever possible and rely on dependency injection/mockito for mocking dependencies.